# how to check association changed use mongodb in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model, and i want to callback when association change.

```
class Database
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String

  belongs_to :user

  after_save :do_something if user_id_changed?  #or 'if user_changed?'

  def do_something
    #do something here
  end

end
```

When i run code so error:
`undefined method 'user_id_changed?' for Database:Class`

How to check association changed use mongodb. 
tks

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
after_save :do_something, if: :user_id_changed?
```

For detail, pls check this [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#conditional-callbacks)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use `changed?` you would need to have your Document class to be `< ActiveRecord::Base` or use http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html